# ¿Cómo mostrar List<string>?

Tags: c#, asp.net

¿Cómo mostrar `List<string>`?

Estoy en el desarrollo de un programa donde, en una clase, tengo una `List<string>`. Tengo que listarla en un GridView.

Tengo el siguiente inconveniente: `System.String[]` es lo que me muestra. ¿En la propiedad set tengo que programar un foreach para recorrerla para poder ver el contenido?

```
public class Periodista
{

    private string _nombre;
    private string _nacionalidad;
    private DateTime _fechaNacimiento;
    private List<string> _premios = new List<string>();

    public List<string> Premios
    {
        get {

                return _premios;
           }
        set { _premios = value;}
    }
```

Lo que tengo es una clase periodista, donde tengo una lista de premios en ella. Al querer traerlos de la base de datos y mostrarlos, me muestra esto el gridview

> ```
> System.String[]
> ```

---

Tengo una clase periodista donde tengo una lista de premios en ella al querer traerlos de la base de datos y mostrarlos me muestra esto el gridview System.String[]

Comment: Hola Alexis, por favor edita la pregunta y agrega el código relacionado (como texto, no como imagen).

Comment: ¿Alguna respuesta te fue de utilidad?

Answer (score 1):

Por lo visto estas utilizando WCF para recuperar la información, por defecto esta configurado para que las listas lleguen como arreglos. Puedes cambiar esto cambiando la configuración al momento de realizar la referencia al servicio web. Haciendo clic en el botón Avanzado... en el dialogo Agregar referencia de servicio.

Espero te sirva.

[image: Configuración al momento de consumir Web service]

Para visualizar la lista de premios puedes utilizar otra grilla:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="_nombre" HeaderText="Nombre" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="_nacionalidad" HeaderText="Nombre" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="_fechaNacimiento" HeaderText="Nombre" />
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        Premios
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:GridView runat="server" ShowHeader="false" Width="100%"
                            DataSource='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem._premios") %>'>
                        </asp:GridView>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Se visualizara de la siguiente manera:
[image: Imagen Resultado]

Answer (score 0):

Puedes darle la lista como un datasource al GridView.
Para ello intenta lo siguiente:

Suponiendo que la id del GridView es "grilla"...

```
grilla.DataSource = milista;
grilla.DataBind();
```

Espero sirva.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta pero eso ya lo tengo programado el tema es que no me lista list que tengo dentro de la clase periodista

Comment: List<Periodista> _ListaP = new MiServicioClient().ListarPeriodistas().ToList();

Comment: GVPeriodistas.DataSource = _ListaP;
                GVPeriodistas.DataBind();

Answer (score 0):

No veo exactamente porque te esta mostrando eso, parece como que sea una lista de string[] aunque no lo sea, mi recomendación es que uses el evento `rowDataBound` para comprobar que le esta llegando realmente al `gridview`

```
protected void GridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
  {
    for (int i = 1; i < e.Row.Cells.Count; i++)
    {
       e.Row.Cells[i].Text;
    }
  }
}

<asp:GridView ID="GridView" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="GridView_RowDataBound" >
```

O directamente usar ese evento para assignarle los valores de la lista

Answer (score -1):

Para recorrer por ejemplo `List<string> MiLista` lo logras con un foreach

```
foreach (string s in MiLista)
   Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

Comment: La pregunta hace referencia a asp.net no una aplicación de consola.